# How to "call" driver ioctl from another driver?

Tags: driver, tty, uart

A user space program can modify the RTS pin of a serial port / UART using an ioctl call. For example:

```
int RTS_flag = TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIS, &RTS_flag);
ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIC, &RTS_flag);
```

Suppose I want to control the RTS pin from a driver. Is it possible to "call" the driver holding the tty and ask it to control the pin for me?  (Rather than figuring out the control registers of the specific device and reading/writing bytes, not to mention instantly supporting all the UART chips supported by the kernel drivers).

What's the proper way of going about that?

For example, in `myDriver`:

```
static const struct file_operations ecp_fileOps =
{
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl,
    .write      = 0,  
    .read       = 0,
    .poll       = 0,
    .open       = lirc_dev_fop_open,
    .release    = lirc_dev_fop_close,
    .llseek     = no_llseek,
};

static long ecp_ioctl(struct file *filep, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    switch (cmd)
    {
        "Call" tty ioctl function...
    }
}
```

**OS INFO**

```
# uname -a
Linux ecp 4.4.127-1.el6.elrepo.i686 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 09:44:43 EDT 2018 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Comment: *"Kernel: 4.4-127 32 bit"*  -- Linux?